# React-native hot reloading triggered on every file key up on WebStorm

Tags: javascript, react-native, webstorm, hot-module-replacement

I am having a issue with hot reloading and WebStorm.

A couple of weeks ago I didn't had this problem, since the hot reloading was just triggering when I focused out from WebStorm. But now every file change it is triggering the hot reloading, and it is very annoying since most of time I didn't finish the logic and it triggers an error.

Someone notice that new behavior when coding react-native with WebStorm?

Comment: 1)Maybe you have Live Edit active? 2) Maybe you are using File Watcher to compile/process some stuff and enabled "Immediate file sync" option there?

Comment: Based on your answer I remebered that I installed eslint plugin. So it was the eslint plugin triggering the hot reloading on every edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just resolved this issue disabling `ESLint plugin` on webstorm, this plugin was triggering the `hot reloading` on every file change, instead on IDE focus out like was before I had installed that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think disabling hot reloading option would help you when your app is on the foreground on your mobile then just go the options menu of the app and disable hot reloading.

If you are on iOS device do ⌘ + D and click on Disable Hot Reloading

I'm not sure but for the android I think it's ⌘ + M(r), if you are not on a mac try Control instead of ⌘

EDIT:  There was problem in your package.json. change your start command in package.json

previously:
"start": "react-native start"

change it to:
 "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"

or you can do one more thing, just reinstall the cli and the command is described below:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
 npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Cheers:)

Comment: I know I can disable hot reloading, in some cases is what I'm doing, but my questions is exactly to solve this problem, thanks for the answer tho

Comment: react native version?

Comment: I just resolved it mate, thanks for your help and time!

Comment: cool, go through the edit, in case i am wrong just correct me.